JQ Parse not returning indexed array just numbers
I have a multi-nested weather dump (Accuweather):
I am trying to get an indexed response/array ([0,...]) to sort - json and/or bash of the values. But my queries are only getting numbers-space separated. My queries in the two examples are ok in that they are getting to the correct position in the JSON, and the correct values, but just returning numbers.
The same when querying a string value, with or without quotes (-r).
Yes, I suppose I could loop through the output, I am just learning jq and know there must be something I am missing in the query to accomplish this. Help please.
Ex: 1 2 3 4 5 spaces only no '[ ]'
Query 1:
drp=$(cat "$HOME/directory/file" | jq '.DailyForecasts[].Day.RainProbability | .')

JSON: -- The query above works as far as returns the correct value/integer output, this is a partial of 5 array sets. Just only returning digits, so: 1 number number number number, not returning in array form.
"Day": {
  "Icon": 2,
  "IconPhrase": "Mostly sunny",
  "HasPrecipitation": false,
  "ShortPhrase": "Mostly sunny and breezy",
  "LongPhrase": "Mostly sunny and breezy",
  "PrecipitationProbability": 1,
  "ThunderstormProbability": 0,
  "RainProbability": 1,
  "SnowProbability": 0,
  "IceProbability": 0,
  "Wind": {
    "Speed": {
      "Value": 15,
      "Unit": "mi/h",
      "UnitType": 9,
...
}   

Query 2:
apg=$(cat "$HOME/directory/file" |
 jq '.DailyForecasts[].AirAndPollen | .[1] | .Value | .')

I've tried to map, etc, number of ways (ex. going for the grass value here).
JSON: -- Same description as Query 1: returning 5 values not in array form. 12, next iteration, etc.
"AirAndPollen": [
  {
    "Name": "AirQuality",
    "Value": 44,
    "Category": "Good",
    "CategoryValue": 1,
    "Type": "Ozone"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Grass",
    "Value": 12,
    "Category": "Moderate",
    "CategoryValue": 2
  },
... 
]

The FULL json:
{"Headline":{"EffectiveDate":"2024-04-03T08:00:00-05:00","EffectiveEpochDate":1712149200,"Severity":7,"Text":"Not as hot Wednesday","Category":"cooler","EndDate":"2024-04-03T20:00:00-05:00","EndEpochDate":1712192400,"MobileLink":"http://www.accuweather.com/en/us/mcallen-tx/78501/daily-weather-forecast/335730?lang=en-us","Link":"http://www.accuweather.com/en/us/mcallen-tx/78501/daily-weather-forecast/335730?lang=en-us"},"DailyForecasts":[{"Date":"2024-03-31T07:00:00-05:00","EpochDate":1711886400,"Sun":{"Rise":"2024-03-31T07:24:00-05:00","EpochRise":1711887840,"Set":"2024-03-31T19:50:00-05:00","EpochSet":1711932600},"Moon":{"Rise":"2024-03-31T01:03:00-05:00","EpochRise":1711864980,"Set":"2024-03-31T11:24:00-05:00","EpochSet":1711902240,"Phase":"WaningGibbous","Age":21},"Temperature":{"Minimum":{"Value":73.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18},"Maximum":{"Value":88.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18}},"RealFeelTemperature":{"Minimum":{"Value":74.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18,"Phrase":"Pleasant"},"Maximum":{"Value":93.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18,"Phrase":"Hot"}},"RealFeelTemperatureShade":{"Minimum":{"Value":74.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18,"Phrase":"Pleasant"},"Maximum":{"Value":90.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18,"Phrase":"Hot"}},"HoursOfSun":3.1,"DegreeDaySummary":{"Heating":{"Value":0.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18},"Cooling":{"Value":15.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18}},"AirAndPollen":[{"Name":"AirQuality","Value":78,"Category":"Moderate","CategoryValue":2,"Type":"Ozone"},{"Name":"Grass","Value":12,"Category":"Moderate","CategoryValue":2},{"Name":"Mold","Value":3250,"Category":"Low","CategoryValue":1},{"Name":"Ragweed","Value":5,"Category":"Low","CategoryValue":1},{"Name":"Tree","Value":50,"Category":"Moderate","CategoryValue":2},{"Name":"UVIndex","Value":4,"Category":"Moderate","CategoryValue":2}],"Day":{"Icon":4,"IconPhrase":"Intermittent clouds","HasPrecipitation":false,"ShortPhrase":"Breezy with clouds and sun","LongPhrase":"A warm breeze with intervals of clouds and sunshine","PrecipitationProbability":2,"ThunderstormProbability":0,"RainProbability":2,"SnowProbability":0,"IceProbability":0,"Wind":{"Speed":{"Value":15.0,"Unit":"mi/h","UnitType":9},"Direction":{"Degrees":153,"Localized":"SSE","English":"SSE"}},"WindGust":{"Speed":{"Value":27.6,"Unit":"mi/h","UnitType":9},"Direction":{"Degrees":170,"Localized":"S","English":"S"}},"TotalLiquid":{"Value":0.0,"Unit":"in","UnitType":1},"Rain":{"Value":0.0,"Unit":"in","UnitType":1},"Snow":{"Value":0.0,"Unit":"in","UnitType":1},"Ice":{"Value":0.0,"Unit":"in","UnitType":1},"HoursOfPrecipitation":0.0,"HoursOfRain":0.0,"HoursOfSnow":0.0,"HoursOfIce":0.0,"CloudCover":85,"Evapotranspiration":{"Value":0.12,"Unit":"in","UnitType":1},"SolarIrradiance":{"Value":2900.4,"Unit":"W/m²","UnitType":33},"RelativeHumidity":{"Minimum":58,"Maximum":88,"Average":68},"WetBulbTemperature":{"Minimum":{"Value":71.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18},"Maximum":{"Value":77.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18},"Average":{"Value":74.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18}},"WetBulbGlobeTemperature":{"Minimum":{"Value":72.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18},"Maximum":{"Value":82.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18},"Average":{"Value":78.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18}}},"Night":{"Icon":36,"IconPhrase":"Intermittent clouds","HasPrecipitation":false,"ShortPhrase":"Breezy early; clearing, humid","LongPhrase":"Breezy in the evening; otherwise, turning out clear and humid","PrecipitationProbability":3,"ThunderstormProbability":0,"RainProbability":3,"SnowProbability":0,"IceProbability":0,"Wind":{"Speed":{"Value":16.1,"Unit":"mi/h","UnitType":9},"Direction":{"Degrees":148,"Localized":"SSE","English":"SSE"}},"WindGust":{"Speed":{"Value":32.2,"Unit":"mi/h","UnitType":9},"Direction":{"Degrees":150,"Localized":"SSE","English":"SSE"}},"TotalLiquid":{"Value":0.0,"Unit":"in","UnitType":1},"Rain":{"Value":0.0,"Unit":"in","UnitType":1},"Snow":{"Value":0.0,"Unit":"in","UnitType":1},"Ice":{"Value":0.0,"Unit":"in","UnitType":1},"HoursOfPrecipitation":0.0,"HoursOfRain":0.0,"HoursOfSnow":0.0,"HoursOfIce":0.0,"CloudCover":75,"Evapotranspiration":{"Value":0.03,"Unit":"in","UnitType":1},"SolarIrradiance":{"Value":35.0,"Unit":"W/m²","UnitType":33},"RelativeHumidity":{"Minimum":76,"Maximum":92,"Average":83},"WetBulbTemperature":{"Minimum":{"Value":72.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18},"Maximum":{"Value":74.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18},"Average":{"Value":73.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18}},"WetBulbGlobeTemperature":{"Minimum":{"Value":74.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18},"Maximum":{"Value":75.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18},"Average":{"Value":74.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18}}},"Sources":["AccuWeather"],"MobileLink":"http://www.accuweather.com/en/us/mcallen-tx/78501/daily-weather-forecast/335730?lang=en-us","Link":"http://www.accuweather.com/en/us/mcallen-tx/78501/daily-weather-forecast/335730?lang=en-us"},{"Date":"2024-04-01T07:00:00-05:00","EpochDate":1711972800,"Sun":{"Rise":"2024-04-01T07:23:00-05:00","EpochRise":1711974180,"Set":"2024-04-01T19:50:00-05:00","EpochSet":1712019000},"Moon":{"Rise":"2024-04-01T02:02:00-05:00","EpochRise":1711954920,"Set":"2024-04-01T12:21:00-05:00","EpochSet":1711992060,"Phase":"Last","Age":22},"Temperature":{"Minimum":{"Value":72.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18},"Maximum":{"Value":93.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18}},"RealFeelTemperature":{"Minimum":{"Value":75.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18,"Phrase":"Pleasant"},"Maximum":{"Value":97.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18,"Phrase":"Hot"}},"RealFeelTemperatureShade":{"Minimum":{"Value":75.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18,"Phrase":"Pleasant"},"Maximum":{"Value":94.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18,"Phrase":"Hot"}},"HoursOfSun":8.4,"DegreeDaySummary":{"Heating":{"Value":0.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18},"Cooling":{"Value":18.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18}},"AirAndPollen":[{"Name":"AirQuality","Value":80,"Category":"Moderate","CategoryValue":2,"Type":"Ozone"},{"Name":"Grass","Value":12,"Category":"Moderate","CategoryValue":2},{"Name":"Mold","Value":3250,"Category":"Low","CategoryValue":1},{"Name":"Ragweed","Value":5,"Category":"Low","CategoryValue":1},{"Name":"Tree","Value":50,"Category":"Moderate","CategoryValue":2},{"Name":"UVIndex","Value":10,"Category":"Very High","CategoryValue":4}],"Day":{"Icon":3,"IconPhrase":"Partly sunny","HasPrecipitation":false,"ShortPhrase":"Partly sunny; breezy, humid","LongPhrase":"Breezy and humid with sunshine and some clouds","PrecipitationProbability":1,"ThunderstormProbability":0,"RainProbability":1,"SnowProbability":0,"IceProbability":0,"Wind":{"Speed":{"Value":18.4,"Unit":"mi/h","UnitType":9},"Direction":{"Degrees":160,"Localized":"SSE","English":"SSE"}},"WindGust":{"Speed":{"Value":41.4,"Unit":"mi/h","UnitType":9},"Direction":{"Degrees":168,"Localized":"SSE","English":"SSE"}},"TotalLiquid":{"Value":0.0,"Unit":"in","UnitType":1},"Rain":{"Value":0.0,"Unit":"in","UnitType":1},"Snow":{"Value":0.0,"Unit":"in","UnitType":1},"Ice":{"Value":0.0,"Unit":"in","UnitType":1},"HoursOfPrecipitation":0.0,"HoursOfRain":0.0,"HoursOfSnow":0.0,"HoursOfIce":0.0,"CloudCover":37,"Evapotranspiration":{"Value":0.19,"Unit":"in","UnitType":1},"SolarIrradiance":{"Value":7608.0,"Unit":"W/m²","UnitType":33},"RelativeHumidity":{"Minimum":47,"Maximum":87,"Average":64},"WetBulbTemperature":{"Minimum":{"Value":73.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18},"Maximum":{"Value":78.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18},"Average":{"Value":76.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18}},"WetBulbGlobeTemperature":{"Minimum":{"Value":75.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18},"Maximum":{"Value":85.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18},"Average":{"Value":81.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18}}},"Night":{"Icon":35,"IconPhrase":"Partly cloudy","HasPrecipitation":false,"ShortPhrase":"Partly cloudy, warm and humid","LongPhrase":"Warm and humid with patchy clouds","PrecipitationProbability":13,"ThunderstormProbability":3,"RainProbability":13,"SnowProbability":0,"IceProbability":0,"Wind":{"Speed":{"Value":10.4,"Unit":"mi/h","UnitType":9},"Direction":{"Degrees":98,"Localized":"E","English":"E"}},"WindGust":{"Speed":{"Value":27.6,"Unit":"mi/h","UnitType":9},"Direction":{"Degrees":146,"Localized":"SE","English":"SE"}},"TotalLiquid":{"Value":0.0,"Unit":"in","UnitType":1},"Rain":{"Value":0.0,"Unit":"in","UnitType":1},"Snow":{"Value":0.0,"Unit":"in","UnitType":1},"Ice":{"Value":0.0,"Unit":"in","UnitType":1},"HoursOfPrecipitation":0.0,"HoursOfRain":0.0,"HoursOfSnow":0.0,"HoursOfIce":0.0,"CloudCover":45,"Evapotranspiration":{"Value":0.02,"Unit":"in","UnitType":1},"SolarIrradiance":{"Value":36.2,"Unit":"W/m²","UnitType":33},"RelativeHumidity":{"Minimum":72,"Maximum":93,"Average":84},"WetBulbTemperature":{"Minimum":{"Value":71.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18},"Maximum":{"Value":75.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18},"Average":{"Value":73.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18}},"WetBulbGlobeTemperature":{"Minimum":{"Value":74.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18},"Maximum":{"Value":79.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18},"Average":{"Value":76.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18}}},"Sources":["AccuWeather"],"MobileLink":"http://www.accuweather.com/en/us/mcallen-tx/78501/daily-weather-forecast/335730?day=1&lang=en-us","Link":"http://www.accuweather.com/en/us/mcallen-tx/78501/daily-weather-forecast/335730?day=1&lang=en-us"},{"Date":"2024-04-02T07:00:00-05:00","EpochDate":1712059200,"Sun":{"Rise":"2024-04-02T07:22:00-05:00","EpochRise":1712060520,"Set":"2024-04-02T19:51:00-05:00","EpochSet":1712105460},"Moon":{"Rise":"2024-04-02T02:59:00-05:00","EpochRise":1712044740,"Set":"2024-04-02T13:25:00-05:00","EpochSet":1712082300,"Phase":"WaningCrescent","Age":23},"Temperature":{"Minimum":{"Value":60.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18},"Maximum":{"Value":94.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18}},"RealFeelTemperature":{"Minimum":{"Value":56.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18,"Phrase":"Cool"},"Maximum":{"Value":93.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18,"Phrase":"Hot"}},"RealFeelTemperatureShade":{"Minimum":{"Value":56.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18,"Phrase":"Cool"},"Maximum":{"Value":90.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18,"Phrase":"Hot"}},"HoursOfSun":4.1,"DegreeDaySummary":{"Heating":{"Value":0.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18},"Cooling":{"Value":12.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18}},"AirAndPollen":[{"Name":"AirQuality","Value":75,"Category":"Moderate","CategoryValue":2,"Type":"Ozone"},{"Name":"Grass","Value":13,"Category":"Moderate","CategoryValue":2},{"Name":"Mold","Value":4388,"Category":"Low","CategoryValue":1},{"Name":"Ragweed","Value":6,"Category":"Low","CategoryValue":1},{"Name":"Tree","Value":55,"Category":"Moderate","CategoryValue":2},{"Name":"UVIndex","Value":8,"Category":"Very High","CategoryValue":4}],"Day":{"Icon":6,"IconPhrase":"Mostly cloudy","HasPrecipitation":false,"ShortPhrase":"Mostly cloudy and breezy","LongPhrase":"Mostly cloudy, breezy and less humid","PrecipitationProbability":7,"ThunderstormProbability":0,"RainProbability":7,"SnowProbability":0,"IceProbability":0,"Wind":{"Speed":{"Value":16.1,"Unit":"mi/h","UnitType":9},"Direction":{"Degrees":1,"Localized":"N","English":"N"}},"WindGust":{"Speed":{"Value":33.4,"Unit":"mi/h","UnitType":9},"Direction":{"Degrees":360,"Localized":"N","English":"N"}},"TotalLiquid":{"Value":0.0,"Unit":"in","UnitType":1},"Rain":{"Value":0.0,"Unit":"in","UnitType":1},"Snow":{"Value":0.0,"Unit":"in","UnitType":1},"Ice":{"Value":0.0,"Unit":"in","UnitType":1},"HoursOfPrecipitation":0.0,"HoursOfRain":0.0,"HoursOfSnow":0.0,"HoursOfIce":0.0,"CloudCover":76,"Evapotranspiration":{"Value":0.21,"Unit":"in","UnitType":1},"SolarIrradiance":{"Value":4941.3,"Unit":"W/m²","UnitType":33},"RelativeHumidity":{"Minimum":17,"Maximum":79,"Average":36},"WetBulbTemperature":{"Minimum":{"Value":61.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18},"Maximum":{"Value":70.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18},"Average":{"Value":65.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18}},"WetBulbGlobeTemperature":{"Minimum":{"Value":72.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18},"Maximum":{"Value":77.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18},"Average":{"Value":74.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18}}},"Night":{"Icon":33,"IconPhrase":"Clear","HasPrecipitation":false,"ShortPhrase":"Clear and cooler","LongPhrase":"Clear and cooler","PrecipitationProbability":10,"ThunderstormProbability":0,"RainProbability":10,"SnowProbability":0,"IceProbability":0,"Wind":{"Speed":{"Value":11.5,"Unit":"mi/h","UnitType":9},"Direction":{"Degrees":15,"Localized":"NNE","English":"NNE"}},"WindGust":{"Speed":{"Value":18.4,"Unit":"mi/h","UnitType":9},"Direction":{"Degrees":7,"Localized":"N","English":"N"}},"TotalLiquid":{"Value":0.0,"Unit":"in","UnitType":1},"Rain":{"Value":0.0,"Unit":"in","UnitType":1},"Snow":{"Value":0.0,"Unit":"in","UnitType":1},"Ice":{"Value":0.0,"Unit":"in","UnitType":1},"HoursOfPrecipitation":0.0,"HoursOfRain":0.0,"HoursOfSnow":0.0,"HoursOfIce":0.0,"CloudCover":0,"Evapotranspiration":{"Value":0.07,"Unit":"in","UnitType":1},"SolarIrradiance":{"Value":42.0,"Unit":"W/m²","UnitType":33},"RelativeHumidity":{"Minimum":24,"Maximum":59,"Average":44},"WetBulbTemperature":{"Minimum":{"Value":52.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18},"Maximum":{"Value":59.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18},"Average":{"Value":56.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18}},"WetBulbGlobeTemperature":{"Minimum":{"Value":57.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18},"Maximum":{"Value":71.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18},"Average":{"Value":63.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18}}},"Sources":["AccuWeather"],"MobileLink":"http://www.accuweather.com/en/us/mcallen-tx/78501/daily-weather-forecast/335730?day=2&lang=en-us","Link":"http://www.accuweather.com/en/us/mcallen-tx/78501/daily-weather-forecast/335730?day=2&lang=en-us"},{"Date":"2024-04-03T07:00:00-05:00","EpochDate":1712145600,"Sun":{"Rise":"2024-04-03T07:21:00-05:00","EpochRise":1712146860,"Set":"2024-04-03T19:51:00-05:00","EpochSet":1712191860},"Moon":{"Rise":"2024-04-03T03:51:00-05:00","EpochRise":1712134260,"Set":"2024-04-03T14:31:00-05:00","EpochSet":1712172660,"Phase":"WaningCrescent","Age":24},"Temperature":{"Minimum":{"Value":56.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18},"Maximum":{"Value":83.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18}},"RealFeelTemperature":{"Minimum":{"Value":54.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18,"Phrase":"Cool"},"Maximum":{"Value":83.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18,"Phrase":"Very Warm"}},"RealFeelTemperatureShade":{"Minimum":{"Value":54.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18,"Phrase":"Cool"},"Maximum":{"Value":80.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18,"Phrase":"Pleasant"}},"HoursOfSun":12.5,"DegreeDaySummary":{"Heating":{"Value":0.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18},"Cooling":{"Value":4.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18}},"AirAndPollen":[{"Name":"AirQuality","Value":73,"Category":"Moderate","CategoryValue":2,"Type":"Ozone"},{"Name":"Grass","Value":29,"Category":"High","CategoryValue":3},{"Name":"Mold","Value":5704,"Category":"Low","CategoryValue":1},{"Name":"Ragweed","Value":7,"Category":"Low","CategoryValue":1},{"Name":"Tree","Value":357,"Category":"High","CategoryValue":3},{"Name":"UVIndex","Value":10,"Category":"Very High","CategoryValue":4}],"Day":{"Icon":1,"IconPhrase":"Sunny","HasPrecipitation":false,"ShortPhrase":"Sunny and not as hot","LongPhrase":"Not as hot but pleasant with plenty of sunshine","PrecipitationProbability":6,"ThunderstormProbability":0,"RainProbability":6,"SnowProbability":0,"IceProbability":0,"Wind":{"Speed":{"Value":10.4,"Unit":"mi/h","UnitType":9},"Direction":{"Degrees":357,"Localized":"N","English":"N"}},"WindGust":{"Speed":{"Value":18.4,"Unit":"mi/h","UnitType":9},"Direction":{"Degrees":346,"Localized":"NNW","English":"NNW"}},"TotalLiquid":{"Value":0.0,"Unit":"in","UnitType":1},"Rain":{"Value":0.0,"Unit":"in","UnitType":1},"Snow":{"Value":0.0,"Unit":"in","UnitType":1},"Ice":{"Value":0.0,"Unit":"in","UnitType":1},"HoursOfPrecipitation":0.0,"HoursOfRain":0.0,"HoursOfSnow":0.0,"HoursOfIce":0.0,"CloudCover":0,"Evapotranspiration":{"Value":0.22,"Unit":"in","UnitType":1},"SolarIrradiance":{"Value":7924.6,"Unit":"W/m²","UnitType":33},"RelativeHumidity":{"Minimum":23,"Maximum":56,"Average":33},"WetBulbTemperature":{"Minimum":{"Value":53.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18},"Maximum":{"Value":59.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18},"Average":{"Value":57.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18}},"WetBulbGlobeTemperature":{"Minimum":{"Value":58.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18},"Maximum":{"Value":71.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18},"Average":{"Value":66.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18}}},"Night":{"Icon":34,"IconPhrase":"Mostly clear","HasPrecipitation":false,"ShortPhrase":"Mainly clear","LongPhrase":"Mainly clear","PrecipitationProbability":10,"ThunderstormProbability":0,"RainProbability":10,"SnowProbability":0,"IceProbability":0,"Wind":{"Speed":{"Value":6.9,"Unit":"mi/h","UnitType":9},"Direction":{"Degrees":131,"Localized":"SE","English":"SE"}},"WindGust":{"Speed":{"Value":13.8,"Unit":"mi/h","UnitType":9},"Direction":{"Degrees":47,"Localized":"NE","English":"NE"}},"TotalLiquid":{"Value":0.0,"Unit":"in","UnitType":1},"Rain":{"Value":0.0,"Unit":"in","UnitType":1},"Snow":{"Value":0.0,"Unit":"in","UnitType":1},"Ice":{"Value":0.0,"Unit":"in","UnitType":1},"HoursOfPrecipitation":0.0,"HoursOfRain":0.0,"HoursOfSnow":0.0,"HoursOfIce":0.0,"CloudCover":11,"Evapotranspiration":{"Value":0.03,"Unit":"in","UnitType":1},"SolarIrradiance":{"Value":45.2,"Unit":"W/m²","UnitType":33},"RelativeHumidity":{"Minimum":30,"Maximum":79,"Average":60},"WetBulbTemperature":{"Minimum":{"Value":53.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18},"Maximum":{"Value":57.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18},"Average":{"Value":54.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18}},"WetBulbGlobeTemperature":{"Minimum":{"Value":56.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18},"Maximum":{"Value":67.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18},"Average":{"Value":60.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18}}},"Sources":["AccuWeather"],"MobileLink":"http://www.accuweather.com/en/us/mcallen-tx/78501/daily-weather-forecast/335730?day=3&lang=en-us","Link":"http://www.accuweather.com/en/us/mcallen-tx/78501/daily-weather-forecast/335730?day=3&lang=en-us"},{"Date":"2024-04-04T07:00:00-05:00","EpochDate":1712232000,"Sun":{"Rise":"2024-04-04T07:20:00-05:00","EpochRise":1712233200,"Set":"2024-04-04T19:52:00-05:00","EpochSet":1712278320},"Moon":{"Rise":"2024-04-04T04:37:00-05:00","EpochRise":1712223420,"Set":"2024-04-04T15:40:00-05:00","EpochSet":1712263200,"Phase":"WaningCrescent","Age":25},"Temperature":{"Minimum":{"Value":58.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18},"Maximum":{"Value":85.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18}},"RealFeelTemperature":{"Minimum":{"Value":56.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18,"Phrase":"Cool"},"Maximum":{"Value":89.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18,"Phrase":"Very Warm"}},"RealFeelTemperatureShade":{"Minimum":{"Value":56.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18,"Phrase":"Cool"},"Maximum":{"Value":82.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18,"Phrase":"Very Warm"}},"HoursOfSun":11.3,"DegreeDaySummary":{"Heating":{"Value":0.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18},"Cooling":{"Value":6.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18}},"AirAndPollen":[{"Name":"AirQuality","Value":76,"Category":"Moderate","CategoryValue":2,"Type":"Ozone"},{"Name":"Grass","Value":69,"Category":"High","CategoryValue":3},{"Name":"Mold","Value":7415,"Category":"Moderate","CategoryValue":2},{"Name":"Ragweed","Value":6,"Category":"Low","CategoryValue":1},{"Name":"Tree","Value":1202,"Category":"High","CategoryValue":3},{"Name":"UVIndex","Value":10,"Category":"Very High","CategoryValue":4}],"Day":{"Icon":2,"IconPhrase":"Mostly sunny","HasPrecipitation":false,"ShortPhrase":"Mostly sunny","LongPhrase":"Mostly sunny","PrecipitationProbability":9,"ThunderstormProbability":0,"RainProbability":9,"SnowProbability":0,"IceProbability":0,"Wind":{"Speed":{"Value":9.2,"Unit":"mi/h","UnitType":9},"Direction":{"Degrees":115,"Localized":"ESE","English":"ESE"}},"WindGust":{"Speed":{"Value":20.7,"Unit":"mi/h","UnitType":9},"Direction":{"Degrees":81,"Localized":"E","English":"E"}},"TotalLiquid":{"Value":0.0,"Unit":"in","UnitType":1},"Rain":{"Value":0.0,"Unit":"in","UnitType":1},"Snow":{"Value":0.0,"Unit":"in","UnitType":1},"Ice":{"Value":0.0,"Unit":"in","UnitType":1},"HoursOfPrecipitation":0.0,"HoursOfRain":0.0,"HoursOfSnow":0.0,"HoursOfIce":0.0,"CloudCover":11,"Evapotranspiration":{"Value":0.21,"Unit":"in","UnitType":1},"SolarIrradiance":{"Value":7955.3,"Unit":"W/m²","UnitType":33},"RelativeHumidity":{"Minimum":26,"Maximum":76,"Average":41},"WetBulbTemperature":{"Minimum":{"Value":55.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18},"Maximum":{"Value":62.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18},"Average":{"Value":60.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18}},"WetBulbGlobeTemperature":{"Minimum":{"Value":59.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18},"Maximum":{"Value":74.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18},"Average":{"Value":69.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18}}},"Night":{"Icon":33,"IconPhrase":"Clear","HasPrecipitation":false,"ShortPhrase":"Clear","LongPhrase":"Clear","PrecipitationProbability":5,"ThunderstormProbability":0,"RainProbability":5,"SnowProbability":0,"IceProbability":0,"Wind":{"Speed":{"Value":9.2,"Unit":"mi/h","UnitType":9},"Direction":{"Degrees":127,"Localized":"SE","English":"SE"}},"WindGust":{"Speed":{"Value":20.7,"Unit":"mi/h","UnitType":9},"Direction":{"Degrees":89,"Localized":"E","English":"E"}},"TotalLiquid":{"Value":0.0,"Unit":"in","UnitType":1},"Rain":{"Value":0.0,"Unit":"in","UnitType":1},"Snow":{"Value":0.0,"Unit":"in","UnitType":1},"Ice":{"Value":0.0,"Unit":"in","UnitType":1},"HoursOfPrecipitation":0.0,"HoursOfRain":0.0,"HoursOfSnow":0.0,"HoursOfIce":0.0,"CloudCover":0,"Evapotranspiration":{"Value":0.03,"Unit":"in","UnitType":1},"SolarIrradiance":{"Value":48.5,"Unit":"W/m²","UnitType":33},"RelativeHumidity":{"Minimum":37,"Maximum":80,"Average":65},"WetBulbTemperature":{"Minimum":{"Value":54.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18},"Maximum":{"Value":58.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18},"Average":{"Value":57.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18}},"WetBulbGlobeTemperature":{"Minimum":{"Value":58.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18},"Maximum":{"Value":66.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18},"Average":{"Value":62.0,"Unit":"F","UnitType":18}}},"Sources":["AccuWeather"],"MobileLink":"http://www.accuweather.com/en/us/mcallen-tx/78501/daily-weather-forecast/335730?day=4&lang=en-us","Link":"http://www.accuweather.com/en/us/mcallen-tx/78501/daily-weather-forecast/335730?day=4&lang=en-us"}]}


Can you include the original JSON?

Wrap it in []'s (and no need for the last | .? jq '[ .DailyForecasts[].Day.RainProbability ]' or something along those lines

Thank you for that. I knew it was something simple. However, now I try to convert to bash array (the desired output). I only get the first value of the array.

... When I try to convert to bash array I only get the first instance of array: '2' in this case. Same with string value (only the first word): 'Breezy'. Ex: arr=($(echo $drp | jq -r '.[]'))  Same with mapfile, same with regular exp. I have modified post to include full json. Thank you so much.

arr=($(echo $drp | jq -r '.[]')) has multiple problems and is fundamentally not the way to populate a shell array with the output of a command, ask a new question about that if you'd like help with it.

To convert all values of an array, you need to map its elements:
.DailyForecasts | map(.Day.RainProbability)

map(f) is equivalent to [.[]|f], so the above can be rewritten to the equivalent:
[.DailyForecasts.[].Day.RainProbability]

Output:
[
  2,
  1,
  7,
  6,
  9
]

Similarly for your second query:
.DailyForecasts | map(.AirAndPollen[1].Value)

or
[.DailyForecasts.[].AirAndPollen[1].Value]

Output:
[
  12,
  12,
  13,
  29,
  69
]

Note that your code is very sensitive to the order of the elements in the array. It looks like you are interested in the "Grass" value (the second element in the array, .[1]), so I would suggest to filter for this element specifically:
.DailyForecasts
| map(.AirAndPollen.[] | select(.Name=="Grass").Value)

